# Why does insert into table with primary key/identity column generate "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" error

Tags: sql, insert, primary-key, identity

Table has a primary key/identity column with seed/increment of 1/1. When I try to insert a record into the table while omitting the primary key column because SQL should automatically assign that column a value, I get the following error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

1. I tried inserting a record while omitting the primary key/identity field.
2. I tried inserting a record with an explicit primary key/identity value and received the following error: "The user did not have permission to write to the column."
3. I tried setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON and received the following error: "Cannot find the object "dbo.temp" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp](
       [ProjectNumber] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [ServiceCenterID] [INT] NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [PK_temp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [ProjectNumber] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   INSERT dbo.temp

   SELECT 1 [ServiceCenterID]

I expect a record to be inserted into the table with the primary key/identity column (projectNumber) automatically assigned a value of 1. Instead I get the error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." even though projectNumber is a IDENTITY column

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the `ProjectNumber`, then you need to bring in two columns.

```
INSERT dbo.temp (ProjectNumber, ServiceCenterID)
    SELECT 1, 1 as [ServiceCenterID];
```

If you want it set automatically, then:

```
INSERT dbo.temp (ServiceCenterID)
    SELECT 1;
```

The key idea in both cases is to list the columns explicitly.  That way, you are less likely to make errors on `INSERT`s.  And, if you do, they should be easier to debug.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.